# Table design for tag-like categories in a directory

Tags: mysql, database-design

I noticed that most directory-like sites have categories created and managed by the site administrators while users choose / select which category they would like to post to. For such implementation, there would always be 2 table; a categories table and a listings table whereby listings table will consist of a column that contains the category ID.

This design is straightforward if there are only a few categories and if you know the categories on hand.

But what if you have a lot of categories (i.e. 2000+ categories) or you allow user to specify their own categories (i.e. tags)?

If we create a category column in the listings table, it'll contain duplicate categories. Likewise, if we create a separate categories table, it too will contain duplicate as the categories are specified by the users.

What is the best practice when it comes to designing database for such scenario?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The number of categories doesn't really change anything, but the UI for selecting 1 out of 10 categories will look very different from the one with 2,000 categories.

Duplicates are prevented by adding appropriate constraints to the database tables. This doesn't change when users can add tags themselves either. A listing have a one-to-one or a one-to-many relation with categories. The former is best implemented as a foreign key in the listing table to the category table. The latter is best implemented as an additional table with two foreign keys; one for category and one for listing. Make the primary key a composite key consisting of the listing key and the category key.

However, what the database **cannot** enforce, is a unique "meaning".
Users may independently create the following categories:

- Java Programming
- Java Porgramming
- Programming, java
- All about Java

... and they might all mean the same thing. That last category may also be a category related to coffe making, but I wouldn't bet on it :)

Stackoverflow has to deal with this, and I suspect you could find information about how if you searched [Meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not to look at wordpress approach to this? WordPress.com is really huge and it has far more than 2000 tags or categories. You can download latest WordPress at www.wordpress.org. Database schema is at wp-admin\includes\schema.php file in plain SQL.